# How can i combine these 3 same jquery code with different classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I use this jquery to add class to certain elements when it's scrolled but i used 3 of them and they all basically same except the classes i use. Since i add them seperately to the page they effect the page speed even if it is minimum so how i can i make them into just one jquery and not three?

Short version: How to combine these 3 into 1?

```
 jQuery(document).on('scroll', (e) => {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 70 ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 70) {
  console.log('now');
      jQuery('.ast-primary-header-bar').addClass('headercoloring');      
    } else {    
console.log('no');
      jQuery('.ast-primary-header-bar').removeClass('headercoloring');
    }
})
```

second:

```
 jQuery(document).on('scroll', (e) => {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 70 ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 70) {
  console.log('now');
      jQuery('.astra-logo-svg').addClass('filterr');      
    } else {    
console.log('no');
      jQuery('.astra-logo-svg').removeClass('filterr');
    }
})
```

third:

```
    jQuery(document).on('scroll', (e) => {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 70 ||
    document.documentElement.scrollTop > 70) {
  console.log('now');
      jQuery('.ast-below-header-bar').addClass('headernarrowing');      
    } else {    
console.log('no');
      jQuery('.ast-below-header-bar').removeClass('headernarrowing');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much starting from outside making all the equal parts as the same codebase.

```
jQuery(document).on('scroll', (e) => {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 70 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 70) {
        console.log('now');
        jQuery('.ast-primary-header-bar').addClass('headercoloring');
        jQuery('.astra-logo-svg').removeClass('filterr');
        jQuery('.ast-below-header-bar').removeClass('headernarrowing');
    } else {
        console.log('no');
        jQuery('.astra-logo-svg').addClass('filterr');
        jQuery('.ast-primary-header-bar').removeClass('headercoloring');
        jQuery('.ast-below-header-bar').addClass('headernarrowing');
    }
})
```